iCloud passwords extension on Chrome asks for code - is there any way to stop this?
I really like iCloud password autofill, but I recently switched to the Arc browser and need to use the iCloud Chrome extension now.
The problem is, every time I start my laptop up anew, it asks for a verification code from a native pop-up that appears.
This adds no security to my laptop, and is often inconvenient.
Is there any way to permanently trust my browser, so I never have to type this code in again? This is one of my few complaints switching over from Safari.
